# Why is multi-conditional mask failing?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Assuming I have a numpy array `X`, an element from it `x`, and a tolerance called `dx`. I would like to create a mask to observe `y` values around that element so I do:

```
for x in X:
    window = (x-dx/2 <= X <= x+dx/2)   
    for y in Y[window]:
        ...
```

Why is the second line failing?

If I use `window = (x-dx/2 <= X) & (X <= x+dx/2)` it works but that's less readable. It is also possible to use `window = np.logical_and(x-dx/2 <= X, X <= x+dx/2)` to increase performance when dealing with large arrays, and that's even less readable.

Comment: Have you tried `window = (x-dx/2 <= X) & (x+dx/2 >= X)`?

Comment: Yes that's equivalent to the second proposition, but why is the multi-condition not working? There is no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: In general, explicit loops should be avoided when working with numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression such as `x < y < z` is evaluated in 2 steps:

1. First `(x < y).__bool__()` is evaluated. If it returns `True` then go to step 2, and if it returns `False` then `x < y < z` is `False`. If it returns anything else then a `TypeError` is raised. `(x < y).__bool__()` might also raise an exception of some kind.
2. If `(x < y).__bool__()` returned `True`, then `y < z` is evaluated. In this case, the value of `x < y < z` is the same as `y < z`. Again, an exception might be raised.

The problem arises in step 1 if either `x` or `y` is a `numpy` array **with multiple elements**. The `numpy` developers felt that there was no "good" way to turn an array with multiple elements into a single `bool` value, and so they decided not to let you, by having `ndarray.__bool__()` raise a `ValueError`.

Note: because of the evaluation order described above you **can** put a `numpy` array in the `z` position, e.g.:

```py
>>> 1 < 2 < np.arange(5)
array([False, False, False, True, True])
```

Comment: Thank you for that in-depth reply. `1 < 2 < np.arange(5)` has me confused, because it's equivalent to `True and 2 < np.arange(5)`, and numpy seems to broadcast the single `True` to `[True, True, True, True, True]` here so that it works. I think it's best to steer clear from those syntaxes then. Thanks!

Comment: The formal documentation for this changed comparisons: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons.  They are evaluated as a sequence of `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z,`  With arrays this often gives rise to the Ambiguity ValueError.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently numpy doesn't support compound statements such as `a < arr < b`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.arange(10)

In [3]: 3 < arr < 7
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

In [4]: (3 < arr) & (arr < 7)
Out[4]:
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False])
```

The compound notation *does* work with plain numbers so it wasn't unreasonable to expect the above to work. Perhaps someone else can explain why this hasn't been implemented in numpy.

```
In [5]: 3 < 2 < 7, 3 < 6 < 7
Out[5]: (False, True)
```

Comment: In general, `numpy` expressions that produce a multielement boolean array cannot be used in Python contexts that expect a scalar boolean.  This ambiguity ValueError comes up quite often in SO questions.  `if` statements, and `or/and` expressions are common scalar boolean contexts.  `numpy` does not alter Python syntax or override the interpreter.  It just implements a `ndarray` class and associated functions.